# Mutex/Semaphore model with shared resource

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, mutex, semaphore

I have a data structure that has two functions: `read` and `write`.

`read` can be called while other `read` functions are running on other threads. However, if `write` is called on any thread, then `read` functions that are called afterwards are paused.

`write` functions can be called but are paused until all other `read` and `write` functions have ended.

After learning about mutexes and semaphores, I thought I would have one mutex for writing.

`mutex writing;`

Whenever `write` is called, it waits till the `writing` mutex is free. It then locks it so any following `write` calls must wait. But here's the problem, write also needs to wait for all readers to finish. There can be infinite readers, so using a semaphore is not actually correct because it's not like there are only `n` locks. There are infinite locks and `write` can only proceed when every one of those locks returns.

How would I structure this so that no race conditions exist? There are hundreds of writers and readers being called from hundreds of threads.

Comment: Research the readers/writers problem. There is a `pthread_rw_lock` though it doesn't necessarily provide "fairness" since the definition of fairness varies.